# How to identify user that purchased subscription with google in app billing on payments page?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

For example, user subscribes to my all, but for some reason server validation fails and subscription isn't saved in my server database.

I go to https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home and see a new subscriber(order) but there are no customer information other than location.

Before purchase I pass a payload, can I see at lease that somethere for that order?

Any other way to pass addition info that I could see in that payments page?

Comment: Are there logs available for failure? Solving that failure should solve your problem.

Comment: @AmodGokhale ofc, my process is mainly debugged and secure, but anyway,  I just want to make sure, that if anything happens, i know by looking at the order in google payments dashboard, what user made that order. Now there are no way to know.